Intersection of sigma algebras generated by shifts
EDIT: Iosif's answer showed that my motivation for this question was mislead.
To keep this question interesting for a broader readership, let us forget about sequence spaces and tail algebras and focus this question on the more abstract problems in questions 1 and 2.
Question 1': Given a Borel subset $A \subseteq Y \times W$ of a product of Polish spaces that satisfies $A = \pi^{-1}(\pi(A))$ with the projection $\pi \colon Z \rightarrow Y$, has it been studied under which conditions there exists a Borel set $B \subseteq Y$ with $A = \pi^{-1}(B)$?
Question 2': Under which conditions is a Borel-sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on a Polish space generated by $\{A \in \mathcal{F} | A \text{ is closed}\}$?
Original formulation below
Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces.
Equip $\bar{X} := X^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $Z := Y \times \bar{X}$ with the product topologies.
Elements of the sequence space will be denoted $\bar{x} = (x_0,x_1,\dots) \in \bar{X}$.
All spaces are endowed with their Borel sigma-algebras, which we denote $\mathcal{B}_Y$, $\mathcal{B}_Z$ etc.
Consider the 'extended' shift map $f \colon Z \rightarrow Z$ defined by $(y,x_0,x_1,\dots) \mapsto (y,x_1,x_2,\dots)$.
I am trying to understand the sigma-algebra
$$\Sigma := \bigcap_{k \geq 1} f^{-k}(\mathcal{B}_Z).$$
My first instinct was to argue '$f^k(y,\bar{x})$ does not depend on $x_0,\dots,x_{k-1}$ and, hence, $\Sigma = \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$ should be generated by the projection $\pi \colon Z \rightarrow Y$.'
Trying to turn this argument into something rigorous exposed some technical difficulties.
(NB: the inclusion $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y) \subseteq \Sigma$ is trivial.)
My approach is as follows.
Take a closed set $A \in \Sigma$, and fix any $(y,\bar{x}) \in A$ and $\bar{x}' \in \bar{X}$.
Denote $\bar{x}_k = (x_0',\dots,x_{k-1}',x_k,x_{k+1},\dots)$ so that $\bar{x}_k \rightarrow \bar{x}'$.
The fact that $f^k(y,\bar{x}_k) = f^k(y,\bar{x})$ and $A \in f^{-k}(\mathcal{B}_Z)$ implies $(y,\bar{x}_k) \in A$.
Since $A$ is closed, it contains the limit $(y,\bar{x}')$.
We have shown $A = \pi^{-1}(\pi(A))$.
If it so happens that $\pi(A) \in \mathcal{B}_Y$, then $A \in \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$.
But of course, in general, $\pi(A)$ is not Borel.
One possibility to proceed is to add the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ be locally compact.
In this case, $A$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets, which would guarantee that $\pi(A)$ is Borel.
Question 1: Can the local compactness assumption be relaxed?
Even if $\pi(A)$ is not itself Borel, are there weaker assumptions that imply the existence of a Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}_Y$ with $A = \pi^{-1}(B)$?
Moving on, suppose we have shown (with or without local compactness) that
$$\mathcal{C} := \{ A \in \Sigma \,|\, A \text{ is closed} \} \subseteq \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y).$$
Can we argue that $\mathcal{C}$ generates $\Sigma$?
This is definitely the case if $\Sigma$ happens to be countably generated.
But it is well known that a sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{B}_Z$ need not be countably generated itself.
At the same time, being countably generated is certainly not necessary: the standard counterexample to the above, namely the countable/cocountable sigma-algebra is still generated by its closed sets.
Question 2: Under which conditions does $\mathcal{C}$ generate $\Sigma$?
More generally, when does $\{ A \in \mathcal{F} \,|\, A \text{ is closed} \}$ generate a Borel-sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$?
Cheers!

Are you familiar with the notion of the tail sigma-algebra?

@RW Thanks! Sometimes it is surprisingly difficult to find a well-known object if only you do not know its name.


$\Sigma = \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$ should be generated by the projection $\pi \colon Z \rightarrow Y$.

This is not true in general. E.g., suppose that $Y=\{0\}$ and $X=\{0,1\}$. Then $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset,Z\}$ over $Z$. On the other hand,
$$\Big\{(y,x_0,x_1,\dots)\in Z\colon\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac12\Big\}\in\Sigma\setminus\{\emptyset,Z\}.$$
So, $\Sigma \ne \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$.

Thanks Iosif, this turned out not to be research level. Btw, how do I see that your proposed set is Borel?

@FlorianR : Each coordinate $x_i$ is a Borel function of $(y,x_0,x_1,\dots)$. The sum of Borel functions is Borel, The upper and lower limits of Borel functions are Borel, So, the proposed set is Borel.

@FlorianR : Do you have a further response to my answer and comment?

No, your answer helped me understand where the problem in my thought process lay. I intentionally posed Questions 1 and 2 in the original question more openly so that they are interesting to others, beyond my specific context. That is why I am waiting to see if someone posts an answer covering those before I accept an answer.

@FlorianR : Well, this is a response. :-) Concerning your second question: (i) "Which" is used when one asks about choosing one or several alternatives in a clearly defined (usually finite and even small) set of alternatives. So, apparently, you meant "what" in place of "which". (ii) As almost all "what"-type questions, your second question is too broad. The best MathOverflow questions are of the yes-or-no kind.

Previous comment continued: (iii) According to MathOverflow guidelines, users should avoid answering posts that "request answers to multiple questions". So, please remove your second question and let us wrap up this matter.
